# What is the proper name to call "non-developer bloggers"?

Tags: nouns, vocabulary, internet

I am looking for a proper name to address a group of people who is not proficient in coding a website (HTML/CSS/JS). A suitable call so not to offend anyone.

Example quotes (that I don't yet feel is correct):

> "Useful codes for regular bloggers."
>
> "Copy-paste solution for unskilled bloggers."
>
> "Code snippets for non-technical developers."

**Update:**

A blogger is technically a website publisher too. Despite his coding skill / knowledge, one might prefer not to code and use available publishing tool as is.

After receiving some good suggestion on the topic, I think I should broaden the term
"non-developer" to something like **bloggers who prefer not to code**.

Do we have a suitable short name for that in English?

Comment: 'content focused' or "content minded' might work.  Sometimes when emphasizing a strength you suggest a lack of well rounded skills.  For example, calling a baseball player a "great defensive player" tends to suggest that their skills at offense are at best average....and would probably even lead a person calling them "a defensive player" to even qualify that they aren't too bad at offense for risk of that being assumed.

Comment: you could try 'artist'

Comment: What about... _"bloggers"_? As opposed to _"developer bloggers"_.

Comment: I don't associate blogging with anything technical. Would all technical skills in the world make you a good blogger? Or would having something interesting to tell make you a good blogger? I mean, you don't get called a newbie driver if you can't fix your own car.

Comment: _Blogger_ is not a term that's connected to developers - so it should be perfectly fine to call a person blogging a _blogger_ regardless of whether he's proficient in coding..

Comment: A blogger is technically a website publisher too. I am looking for the appropriate term for **bloggers who prefer not to code** (despite his coding skill / knowledge)

Comment: Who said the term "blogger" denotes "developer / coder"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The option that comes to mind, focusing on what they actually do, is ***content creators***.  This is a pretty common term these days.

Here are a few examples:

> [The 5 Habits of Highly Successful Content Creators](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/5-habits-of-highly-successful-content-creators-list)
>   [What Type Of Content Creator Are You? A Visual Guide To Your Copywriting Identity](https://coschedule.com/blog/type-content-creator/)
>   [The Unstoppable Rise of the Digital Content Creator](http://www.copyblogger.com/long-live-digital-content/)

Another option would be ***blog authors*** -- that's what I was called back when I did that for a living.

Answer (score 4):

Focus on labelling your content rather than who may be viewing it. Idioms such as “101” or “best practise” may be appropriate.

Comment: Well mentioned. Target audience would be proficient enough at coding but choose to use ready made codes (less work)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

> non-developer bloggers

Or

> non-coding bloggers

Or

> "WYSIWYG" bloggers

WYSIWYG is an acronym that means "what you see is what is what you get" and is a common term for modern "make your own website" and various other editors.

Answer (score 0):

Civilians. :-)

**Newbie** comes to mind.

> An inexperienced newcomer to a particular activity.
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/newbie).

"Copy-paste solution for newbie bloggers."

"Code snippets for newbie developers."

Comment: Try googling "newbie blogger".

Comment: Not being able to code doesn't have anything to do with being a new blogger. This is just insulting to seasoned bloggers.

Comment: @curiousdannii Read Nik's question, especially the 3rd sentence. I was just answering what was asked. :-) Please don't read more into the answer than what was stated.