# Is there a better term for "non-developer"?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are some things only a developer can do. When I have a task that doesn't require a developer -- that anybody can do -- and I need to call that out, I'm stuck for a great way to describe those people. "Non-developer" is the pithiest, most descriptive one I can think of, but I do not love it.

For instance:

> This UI would enable non-developers to alter the app configuration.

Though it's a different [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/397752/16057), seems I'm not alone.

---

**Clarification:** The people I'm imagining are using an app which helps to create apps; therefore, anything involving *user* is unhelpfully ambiguous. They are not system admins, either. Probably the best analogy is designers, but that has a specific meaning in this world (UX & graphic designers), and I don't mean them either.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence where you would use the term?

Comment: @Laurel Done, good suggestion.

Comment: If changes such as variable definitions, custom labels or parameter changes, can be made by people other than developers then they will be made by users of the system. The normal description of such changes is _user definable_ or _user configurable_.

Comment: All true, @BoldBen, and thanks, but doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @ClayBridges More like _system administrators_ perhaps?

Comment: If it doesn't have to be serious, how about *muggles*?

Comment: @samgak Sure, or "civilians". Neither beats "non-developers" for my purposes.

Comment: @BoldBen Not sysads, addressed in-question with a clarification.

Comment: @ClayBridges You should remove *that anybody can do* from the text of your question if you're looking for something that only designers can do.

Comment: @JasonBassford It's not only designers, that's just an analogy.

Comment: So, I'm at a loss. I've seen your edit but I have an issue with your description, namely the part where a person who is helping to create the app but is not, say, "coding" the app, is a "non-developer", though they are people actively involved with the development of the app, just not by programming means. If anything, I think you've conflated a programmer's task as equivalent to being a developer, when the truth is that there is a lot involved in the development process (of any given thing, could be animation, drawing, design, sound production, etc), that requires no programming skill.

Comment: I think this is tough because the colloquialism we tend to use for someone who programs an app is then its developer, but what of the auxiliary people who aren't implementing the logic? I would actually argue and say they are, in fact, developers, just not "programming" developers... so, I think the term you're looking for is "non-coder" or "non-coding developer"

Comment: @psosuna I take your point generally, but as a term of art -- or at least in our _argot_ -- coder and developer are synonymous, and developer is more common these days.

Comment: @ClayBridges Then why not go with designer?

Comment: @psosuna Designer has a specific meaning in this domain, and these users would not be designers.

Comment: @ClayBridges Then I suppose it really is a matter of who your audience is. We've established that these people are not users in the sense of an end user. We've established that they aren't sysadmins, either. They don't develop the app... then, who are they?

Answer (score 1):

Drawing from a comment given to this question, but rephrasing it to be applicable to your example sentence, this seems appropriate:

> This UI would enable **regular users** to alter the app configuration.

Comment: I think OP is thinking more along the lines of assigning tasks at work to resources based on capability.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that a developer would develop the application, and any capability that is borne out of this app as a user-driven experience would then automatically deem those who are not inherently the developers of the app to be its ***Users***. In your current wording, it sounds clunky to just stick the word ***user*** as a drop-in replacement for ***non-developer***, so consider a change in wording:

> This UI allows ***any user*** to change the app configuration.

If the truth is that it isn't intuitive enough to enable "just any user" to do this, you'd want to make a clear note of it (i.e. it requires admin privileges), and so that would make your phrasing become:

> This UI allows the ***system administrator*** to change the app configuration.

Really, the real heart of the question is more directly: Who is your target audience? If it is the general, everyday user, or an advanced, power user, or a system administrator, all of which are "non-developers", that has some weight on what you're trying to describe.

EDIT: After seeing your edit, I believe the term you're after is ***non-coding developer***. It sounds as if you mean to reference the people who work on developing this app, however are not involved with the coding of it.

Answer (score -2):

Unless developers have special credentials, the UI enables, rather than allows, general users wider functionality. If you want to be precise, you'll have to go for less pithy wording, such as "The UI makes altering the app configuration simple enough for the general user to perform".